# How do I display data from one worksheet in Excel on another worksheet and display that data in different cell locations, not just a filtered table

Tags: excel, database, forms, excel-formula, office365

My ability to Google effectively has left my body because I can't find a solution and I'm convinced it's going to be super simple.

I have a large database of information with let's say 20 columns and several hundred rows. I want to make a new worksheet I could use to present to someone the information in a much clearer way. Let's call the main database "Database" and the second sheet "Display Sheet".

I want to have a simple drop down menu that pulls from a name in column A from Database and then it displays the different bits of information from the same row in individual cells I choose on Display Sheet.

For example, on Display Sheet I have the dropdown list in cell A1 that is currently pulling information from Database cell A8. I want Display Sheet cell C2 to show Database cell G8 and Display Sheet cell C4 to show Database cell B8. Then if I change the dropdown in Display Sheet to be showing Database cell A20, cells C2 and C4 both update to show that row and so on.

I am essentially trying to create a form that simply displays information from Database in Display Sheet, but if I even touch the word "form" on Google searches its all about data entry forms and nothing I find is about just displaying data. I don't want anything fancy, I just want to be able to say that data from column XYZ goes in whichever cells I choose once a row is selected via the drop down. I vaguely recall that this was basically what Access did in a way, but I can't use that so need it all in the same workbook.

I tried to follow some guides and thought that the FILTER formula was what I was after, but it doesn't seem to work at all whether I refer to the table name or a defined data range name. I also tried to see if pivot tables would work for me and I just don't understand them well enough at all. Most of the guides I've found simply pull a filtered table across to wherever you want to show it, but I don't want my data in a table when showing it to others.

Comment: Simply put few sample data then desired output. Explain in brief what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Harun24hr I am trying to pull data from one worksheet to another using a drowpdown on the second sheet that pulls from one column on the first, but show the rest of the data from the row I'm pulling from in different individual cells I choose